# Modify Variables in Laravel Package from outside

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel Package where I filter Users that are fetched from the database with a User Eloquent Model. So I have something like

```
if ($request->get('search')) {
         User::where('email', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
...
```

Now I want to add ore preprocess some filters on the Users before this is done from the project itself. What first came to my mind is to fire an event like

```
event(new UserFilterStart($users));
```

where I modify Users before i run the filters. So the code would look like this:

```
  $users = User::all();
  event(new UserFilterStart($users));

  if ($request->get('search')) {
       $users->where('email', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
             ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
             ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
```

I did not manage to hand over the variable by reference, so i can manipulate it. Which is probably a good thing, because then this might have been my final solution.
I get that it is not the way Events should be used and I am looking for alternatives. How can I achieve to inject/modify the code from the package? Considering that I own this package.

Comment: How are your listeners doing the modifications?

Comment: In the end i tried to modify in the Event Constructor like that:
    public function __construct(&$users)
    {
        $users = $users->where('first_name', 'Ozella');
    }

Comment: Which I did just to test if I am able to modify what i got from 
 event(new UserFilterStart($users));

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/returning-values-from-listeners?page=0#reply=76681

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/action-hooks-filters-system

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it turned out that it just works fine with the Event. I just made a mistake somewhere else. Are there any real shortcomings if I use Events like that?